# Why are 'python' and `py` pointing to different user sites

Tags: python

I think something funky is going on with my python installation of python 3.7. Is the below results of using `py` or `python` supposed to return different results?

```
C:\Users\maksim\WikiChron>py -m site --user-site
C:\Users\maksim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages

C:\Users\maksim\WikiChron>python -m site --user-site
C:\Users\maksim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that you installed Python 3.7 on the path, but only python 3.6 had the `py` association. Try running `where py*` and `where python*` to observe the locations of the binaries.

Also look at `echo %PATH%` if you are unsure what your current path is.

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't it be the other way around since py shows the user site under Python37